# Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $hasil=mysqli_query($connect, $ambil);
$hasil_id=$hasil['id'];
$hasil_name=$hasil['name'];
$hasil_email=$hasil['email'];
$hasil_comment=$hasil['comment'];
```

I got this fatal error from the code above, is it something to do with the php version? especialy when using mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edits below. You're trying to use the mysqli result as an array.

```
  $hasil=mysqli_query($connect, $ambil);
  //Assuming you're expecting a single result
  $hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil); //Create array from first result
  $hasil_id=$hasil['id'];
  $hasil_name=$hasil['name'];
  $hasil_email=$hasil['email'];
  $hasil_comment=$hasil['comment'];
```

Comment: Should specify the resulttype variable as MYSQLI_ASSOC to get the data in associative indices - `$hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1):

Use mysqli_fetch_assoc or mysqli_fetch_array to fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
query = "SELECT 1";
```

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc()